# Make new column based on values in other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to introduce a new col in df based on other col values.
If c1-c3 cols have only 1 unique value then that unique value will go into c4 col.
If c1-c3 cols have two different values then "both" will go into c4 col.
NaN should not be considered as a valid value. Only c2 and c3 have a few NaNs.

Minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                     "c1": ["left", "right", "right", "left", "left","right"], 
                     "c2": ["left", "right", "right", "right", "NaN","right"], 
                     "c3": ["NaN", "NaN", "left", "NaN", "left","right"]})
```

Required df:

```
answerdf = pd.DataFrame({
                     "c1": ["left", "right", "right", "left", "left","right"], 
                     "c2": ["left", "right", "right", "right", "NaN","right"], 
                     "c3": ["NaN", "NaN", "left", "NaN", "left","right"], 
                        "c4":["left", "right", "both", "both", "left","right"] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "c1": ["left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right"],
    "c2": ["left", "right", "right", "right", np.nan, "right"],
    "c3": [np.nan, np.nan, "left", np.nan, "left", "right"]
})

def worker(row):
    if "left" in row.values and "right" in row.values:
        return "both"
    if "left" in row.values:
        return "left"
    if "right" in row.values:
        return "right"
    return np.nan

df["c4"] = df[["c1", "c2", "c3"]].apply(worker, axis=1)
```

This returns nan if neither left nor right is given and might be easier to understand

Output

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4
0   left    left    NaN     left
1   right   right   NaN     right
2   right   right   left    both
3   left    right   NaN     both
4   left    NaN     left    left
5   right   right   right   right
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apply to create column c4 with lambda function to check the number of unique values.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "c1": ["left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right"],
    "c2": ["left", "right", "right", "right", np.nan, "right"],
    "c3": [np.nan, np.nan, "left", np.nan, "left", "right"]
})

unique_values = lambda x: x.nunique(dropna=True)

df["c4"] = df[["c1", "c2", "c3"]].apply(unique_values, axis=1).map({1: lambda x: x.index[0], 2: "both"})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      c1     c2     c3                                     c4
0   left   left    NaN  <function <lambda> at 0x7f2c9108d4c0>
1  right  right    NaN  <function <lambda> at 0x7f2c9108d4c0>
2  right  right   left                                   both
3   left  right    NaN                                   both
4   left    NaN   left  <function <lambda> at 0x7f2c9108d4c0>
5  right  right  right  <function <lambda> at 0x7f2c9108d4c0>
```

Comment: "both" entries are fine but the unique entries are not, unique entries are read as <function <lambda> at 0x0000019305D2AB80>.  They should be "left" or "right"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#convert string 'NaN' to np.NaN
df = df.where(df.ne('NaN'))

#find the max value per row, and in rows where there are more than one unique value, make both
df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg('max').where(df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1),'both')
```